# Combine common Transloco config with project-specific variable

Tags: angular, transloco

I'm trying to implement Transloco in my Angular application that consists of a library and multiple SPA projects. I would like to have one global configuration class in the library project `common` and extend that with a production mode variable that the library does not have access to.

Currently, I have the following working configuration architecture:

*transloco-common-config.module.ts* (in `common` library):

```js
@NgModule()
export class TranslocoCommonConfig implements TranslocoConfig {
    public defaultLang = 'en';
    public availableLangs: string[] = [];
    public reRenderOnLangChange = true;

    constructor(private localeService: LocaleService) {
        this.availableLangs = this.localeService.getAvailableLanguages();
    }
}
```

Which I can successfully use in an SPA project-specific module like this:

```js
@NgModule({
    exports: [TranslocoModule],
    providers: [
        { provide: TRANSLOCO_CONFIG, useClass: TranslocoCommonConfig },
        { provide: TRANSLOCO_LOADER, useClass: TranslocoHttpLoader },
    ],
})
export class TranslocoRootModule {
}
```

The available languages are correctly loaded through `LocaleService` and Transloco works in the SPA project as expected.

To extend this configuration **in the SPA project**, my intuition is to use the forRoot() pattern. I modified the common configuration module into this:

```js
class TranslocoCommonConfigOptions {
    productionMode = true;
}

@NgModule()
export class TranslocoCommonConfig implements TranslocoConfig {
    public defaultLang = 'en';
    public availableLangs: string[] = [];
    public reRenderOnLangChange = true;

    constructor(private localeService: LocaleService) {
        this.availableLangs = this.localeService.getAvailableLanguages();
    }

    static forRoot(options: TranslocoCommonConfigOptions): ModuleWithProviders<TranslocoCommonConfig> {
        return {
            ngModule: TranslocoCommonConfig,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: TranslocoCommonConfigOptions,
                    useValue: options,
                },
            ],
        };
    }
}
```

To my understanding, this should be correct. However, I'm struggling to use this correctly in the SPA project. If I modify the `TranslocoRootModule` class to provide `TRANSLOCO_CONFIG` like this:

```js
{ provide: TRANSLOCO_CONFIG, useClass: TranslocoCommonConfig.forRoot({ productionMode: true }) }
```

I get the following error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ provide: InjectionToken<TranslocoConfig>; useClass: ModuleWithProviders<TranslocoCommonConfig>; }' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.   Types of property 'useClass' are incompatible.     Type 'ModuleWithProviders<TranslocoCommonConfig>' is missing the following properties from type 'Type<any>': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more.
```

How should I implement this with preferably minimal boilerplate code (I have five SPA projects and would like to have as little duplicate code as possible)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating two library modules for Transloco configuration.

`TranslocoCommonConfigModule` is responsible for the actual configuration:

```js
export class TranslocoCommonConfigOptions {
    productionMode: boolean;
    loader: Type<TranslocoLoader>;
}

/**
 * Global configuration for the Transloco library. Accepts a `TranslocoCommonConfigOptions`
 * configuration object to dynamically set `TranslocoConfig.prodMode`.
 */
@NgModule()
export class TranslocoCommonConfigModule implements TranslocoConfig {
    // Static and global configuration:
    defaultLang = 'en';
    reRenderOnLangChange = true;

    // Dynamic configuration:
    availableLangs: string[] = [];
    prodMode = true;

    constructor(private localeService: LocaleService, config: TranslocoCommonConfigOptions) {
        this.availableLangs = this.localeService.getAvailableLanguages();
        this.prodMode = config.productionMode;
    }
}
```

While `TranslocoCommonModule` is resposible for injecting the required service and configuration object via the `forRoot` method:

```js
/**
 * Common module for importing Transloco configuration in frontends with minimal boilerplate.
 *
 * Uses the `forRoot()` paradigm to inject `environment.production` dynamically from a frontend along with
 * a frontend-specific translation loader. The rest of `TranslocoConfig` options are global and provided by
 * `TranslocoCommonConfigModule`.
 */
@NgModule()
export class TranslocoCommonModule {
    static forRoot(options: TranslocoCommonConfigOptions): ModuleWithProviders<TranslocoCommonModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: TranslocoCommonModule,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: TRANSLOCO_CONFIG,
                    useFactory: (localeService: LocaleService) =>
                        new TranslocoCommonConfigModule(localeService, options),
                    deps: [LocaleService],
                },
                {
                    provide: TRANSLOCO_LOADER,
                    useClass: options.loader,
                },
            ],
        };
    }
}
```

After implementing a frontend-specific translation file loader, the configuration can be imported in a module like so:

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        TranslocoCommonModule.forRoot({
            productionMode: environment.production,
            loader: TranslocoHttpLoader,
        }),
    ],
})
```